# Почему потоки не работают параллельно?

Tags: java, многопоточность, потоки-данных

Почему потоки не работают параллельно?

И почему общий ресурс `result` равен 0?

```
public class Task1 {
    int result;

    public void increment(){
        this.result++;
    }

    public void decrement(){
        this.result--;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Task1 t1= new Task1();
        new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
                t1.increment();
                t1.decrement();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"  result= "+t1.result);
            }
            }
        }.start();

        new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
                t1.increment();
                t1.decrement();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"  result= "+t1.result);
            }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}

Outline:
Thread-1 - 0
...
Thread-2 - 0
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А чего вы, собственно, ожидали? Вы увеличиваете `result` на 1, а затем уменьшаете его на 1. Исходя из элементарной арифметики после отработки кода он будет равен именно нулю. Насчёт параллельности: с чего вы взяли, что они работают не параллельно? Вот я запускаю их, и [вывод от обоих потоков идёт вперемежку](http://ideone.com/Zv7lW1):

```
   public class Main {
            int result;

        public void increment(){
            this.result++;
        }

        public void decrement(){
            this.result--;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            final Main t1= new Main();
            new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
                    t1.increment();
                    t1.decrement();
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"  result= "+t1.result);
                }
                }
            }.start();

            new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                        for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
                    t1.increment();
                    t1.decrement();
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"  result= "+t1.result);
                }
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Я ожидал что когда 1 поток увеличит значение счетчика и заснет, подберется второй и увеличит это значение, потом первый проснется и уменьшит на 1. В результате значение счетчика будет 1. И вывод будет не равен 0. 
В данном коде потоки не засыпают, но когда засыпали результат не менялся!

Comment: Во первых, если у Вас процессор с несколькими ядрами (или ядро одно, но с [hyper threading](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading)), то команды в потоках в самом деле выполняются параллельно.

Во вторых, даже в случае одного потока команд 10000 "оборотов" цикла величина слишком маленькая для переключения между потоками (в такой ситуации они будут переключаться с частотой прерываний от системного таймера. 100 или 1000 раз в секунду).

--

По поводу "но когда засыпали". А Вы попробуйте вставить sleep() на *случайное* время между increment и decrement.

Comment: @JAVAvladuxa: Потоки не засыпают по вашему желанию, они _могут_ заснуть в любой момент. А могут и не заснуть. Это раз. Во-вторых, несинхронизированный доступ к переменной из разных потоков может привести к чему угодно: без синхронизации (=memory barrier) вид на одну и ту же память у разных потоков имеет право отличаться.

Почитайте: [[раз]](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-02-2001/jw-0209-double.html), [[два]](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/cpj/jmm.html), [[три]](http://erdani.com/publications/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf).